# No module named Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have a small script in python2.7 that I want to convert into Windows executable. I use `pyinstaller` for this.

The script:

```
import sys 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


def get_inputs():
    coor = raw_input(">>>top x left: ").replace(" ", "")
    top, left = coor.split("x")
    top = int(top.strip())
    left = int(left.strip())
    return top, left 

def plot_location(top, left):
    img= mpimg.imread('nbahalfcourt.jpg')
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.scatter(left, top)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

def main():
    top, left = get_inputs()
    plot_location(top, left)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "Input top x left coordinates (no space) eg: 44x232"

    run = True 
    while run:
        main()
```

Basically, the script just plots a point on a grid.

The converting process finishes successfully. When I run the .exe however I've got the `ImportError` (see below) even though I have no reference to `Tkinter` anywhere.

[image]

What could went wrong here?

Comment: I have a feeling that `matplotlib` uses the `Tkinter` module internally, but imports it in a non-standard way. Then `pyinstaller` doesn't notice Tkinter is needed, and subsequently doesn't bundle it into the executable. I wonder if explicitly putting `import Tkinter` at the top of your script would help?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks buddy. Post it as an answer if you wish, so I can accept for the record.

Comment: explicitly importing them so `pyinstaller` can definitely see them is a perfectly good solution, there's also command line flag for explicitly telling `pyinstaller` to include extra modules `--hidden-import=Tkinter`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling that `matplotlib` uses the `Tkinter` module internally, but imports it in a non-standard way. Then `pyinstaller` doesn't notice Tkinter is needed, and subsequently doesn't bundle it into the executable.

Try explicitly putting `import Tkinter` at the top of your script.

Comment: Just for the record, I had to `import FileDialog` along with the Tkinter import.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and none of the solutions here worked. I was using Pyinstaller 3.2 (the latest version at the time) and everything was fixed (and no import statements needed) when I upgraded to the latest developer version using

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

This seems to indicate that at the times of writing this that all the kinks to this issue are still being worked out

**EDIT**: As of January 15 2017 Pyinstaller version 3.2.1 was released. I now use this and it solves this issue along with others like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39135408/2734863) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40274354/2734863) that I could previously only solve by using the developer version. So I highly recommend upgrading to the latest version if you haven't already.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. Also using 3.2 and getting import error for Tkinter. Installing the latest developer version resolved it thanks.

Comment: Also for me using the 3.3 dev version was the only way to fix the issue, thanks