# Pyinstaller is missing modulename._modulename

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to build an `.exe` file on windows including a QT GUI and some image read and write functions. In my main python file, I do `import tifffile` for reading `.tiff` images. Pyinstaller compiles my project without errors. When I run it, I get a warning in my terminal saying:

`path_to_my_project\tifffile\tiffffile.py:8211: UserWarning: No module named 'tifffile._tifffile' Functionality might be degraded or be slow.`

However, I can use the parts of my app that use the corresponding functions from the `tifffile` module. My question now is, how I can fix this or if it's save to ignore, how to suppress the warning.

That's the conda environment I'm using if of any importance:

```
altgraph                  0.16.1                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     1
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_1
dc-imgproc                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
future                    0.17.1                   pypi_0    pypi
hdf5                      1.8.20               hac2f561_1
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
intel-openmp              2019.5                      281
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
libopencv                 3.4.2                h20b85fd_0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libtiff                   4.0.10               hb898794_2
macholib                  1.11                     pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2019.5                      281
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h343c172_0
numpy                     1.16.5           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.16.5           py37hc3f5095_0
opencv                    3.4.2            py37h40b0b35_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_0
pefile                    2019.4.18                pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.2.2                   py37_0
py-opencv                 3.4.2            py37hc319ecb_0
pyinstaller               3.5.dev0+gb54a15d7          pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyqtgraph                 0.10.0           py37h28b3542_3
python                    3.7.4                h5263a28_0
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h29ff71c_0
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
sqlite                    3.29.0               he774522_0
tifffile                  0.15.1          py37h452e1ab_1001    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_0
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

**Update** I can reproduce the behaviour, if I put only `import tifffile` into an empty python file and run pyinstaller on it.

Comment: Can you tell us how you're importing? My intuition tells me it could be a problem with relative imports.

Comment: I do have `import tifffile` in several modules of my package. There's one in my main module and some more in submodules. In all of the it's a simple `import tifffile`.

Comment: Could it have something to do with missing `tifffile.c` as described in the source [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/external/tifffile/tifffile.py#L68) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/external/tifffile/tifffile.py#L307)?

Comment: @djvg Yes. That could be very much the reason. I'm gonna try bundle that up manually.

Comment: This lead me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274354/pyinstaller-exe-cannot-find-tiffile-module-loading-of-some-compressed-images

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't fix my problem.